# C++ not showing cout in Xcode console but runs perfectly in Terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, cout

Basically i am running a simple program in `Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162)`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a;   
    cout << "What is your age: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "My age is " << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have seen different questions about `cout` need to be flushed and all [std::cout won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858262/stdcout-wont-print) and [Xcode debugger not showing C++ cout output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218138/xcode-debugger-not-showing-c-cout-output). The Xcode debugger does not print `cout` until i put `\n or endl`. But, it works perfectly fine on terminal.

What if i had to use `What is your age:` and the user input age in the single line rather than the next line putting `\n and endl`?

This is what the Xcode debugger shows after build and run

[image: This is what the Xcode debugger shows after build and run]

This is when user inputs and it displays the result

[image: This is when user inputs and displays the result]

This is on the terminal and this is what exactly what i need the output on the Xcode debugger.

[image: This is on the terminal]

Comment: Considering that it works fine with terminal but not with xcode, I would look into the xcode compiler and linker options in the settings first... maybe you'll find something interesting there.

Comment: A new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160533/xcode8-program-is-not-executing-correctly seems to have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing some research, there seems to be bug on `cin and cout` stream on `Xcode Version 8.3 Build 8E162` released on `Mar 27, 2017`.
Degrading to `Xcode Version 8.2.1` works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You already solved your problem yourself: `std::cout` uses buffered output and should always be flushed. You can achieve this by either using `std::cout << "What is your age? << std::flush`, by using `std::cout.flush()` or by adding a line break like `std::endl` which flushes implicitly.

A complete solution could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;   
    cout << "What is your age: " << flush;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "My age is " << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: still it does not print, `what is your age` , first rather it waits for an input from user and gives the same result like this
    20
    What is your ageMy age is 20

Comment: Does it work when you add a line break like `\n` or `std::endl` ?

Comment: yes it works, but i do want to print `what is your age` and ask input to the user on a same line rather than the next line.

Comment: Hm, all resources I've found so far tell that XCode won't output until the line is terminated by a line break. A really strange behavior! Sorry, but I have no other solution.