# Xcode std::cout output acting odd

Tags: c++, xcode, output, cout, buffered

I've been using Xcode for 2 years and have written quite a few C++ command line applications.  For the past few months, I've abandoned command line applications and have focused on GUI applications, but after coming back to some older command line applications, I noticed that `std::cout` isn't working the way I last remember.  If I have a `cout` statement such as "enter age: " before a `cin` statement, when running the app in Xcode, it no longer shows the cout statement first, but rather after the input from `cin`.  I read somewhere that the output was buffered and required an '\n' in order to display the text line, but to my knowledge, I never used to have to do this.  Did something change in a newer version of Xcode (I keep Xcode updated entirely)?  I use to be able to print items to the screen without needing a newline in order to do it.  My old applications are no longer working correctly because of this.  Is there a setting somewhere to change it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should add a code example of exactly what you mean so we can have a better idea.

Comment: Turns out I'm not the only one with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174109/in-xcode-8-3-update-c-c-programming-printf-does-not-give-output-without-newli/43484220#43484220

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75035

Comment: I did a bit of searching before posting this and only found these after I posted.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess 8.3.2 is the answer!  This update just popped up on my comp:

[image]